# Asp.Net MVC a lot of constants to handle controller/action redirections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, constants

Is it just me or has anyone else been annoyed by the fact that we have to use a lot of constants to handle redirections from one action to another across different controllers. I have tried to implement a reflection based approch to tackle this issue, but was wondering how others have approached this ( If you have seen this as an issue , of course :) )

As an example, what I did is implemented something like this to get an action name.

```
  public static string ActionName(Func<ActionResult> methodContainer)
        {
            return methodContainer.Method.Name;
        }
```

and to get the controller name,

```
   public static string ControllerName<T>() where T : class
        {
            Type t = typeof (T);
            return t.Name.Replace(ControllerConstants.Controller, string.Empty);
        }
```

Any better approaches than this?

/Bumble Bee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out MVCContrib library, link below addresses exactly the issue you're dealing with...it's been around since MVC v1.

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction&referringTitle=Documentation

It's also on nuget, so it should be easy to give it a spin.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree that you should use supported libraries when available instead of rolling your own I think it worth sharing that it is actually rather straigth forward to implement RedirectToAction. The below code is not complete of course but the general idea holds and can be used to turn a lot of reflection based logic into type safe logic.

```
string ActionLink<TController, T>(Expression<Func<TController,T>> actionExpression, bool useQueryString = false)
        {
            var controllerName = typeof(T).Name;
            const string controllerPostfix = "Controller";
            if (controllerName.EndsWith(controllerPostfix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.Length - controllerPostfix.Length);
            }
            var expBody = (MethodCallExpression)actionExpression.Body;
            var method = expBody.Method;
            var parameters = method.GetParameters().ToArray();
            var arguments = string.Empty;
            if (useQueryString){
                arguments = GetQuerystring(expBody, parameters);
            } else{
                if (parameters.Length > 0)
                {
                    arguments = "/" + string.Join
                                            ("/",
                                             expBody.Arguments.Select
                                                 ((arg, i) => string.Format("{0}",GetValue(arg))).
                                                 ToArray());
                }

            }
            return "~/" + controllerName + "/" + expBody.Method.Name + arguments;
        }
```

As I said the above doesn't handle all possibilities (and two methods used are excluded for brevity).
and there's no error handling expected users to behave nice but the above code makes it possible to write

ACtionLink((MyController c=> c.ShowMeTheMoney(ThreatenWithGun : false, Shout : true));

possible and would return "~/My/ShowMeTheMoney/false/true". So it doesn't take much effort to turn a type safe expression into a string (or any other format) when ever needed and most of what is needed to do that can be reused between conpletely different scenarios (such as the GetValue method used above that is capable of traversing an expression tree to get the value represented by that expression tree)

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously look at fubumvc and it's actions. It addresses the issue much better. Also, the authors are super helpful and responsive.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know, even monorail is pretty good. But now that we have something solid from MS I think it is best to stick with it untill it is proven otherwise. So , thanks sor the suggestion, but I wanna know how this is handled in asp.net mvc ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your action name extraction method is simply incorrect. If you use `ActionName` attribute on your actions, your method will return incorrect action name. If you want to eliminate use of strings and make less effort on writing constants, try [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). It will merely remove all need for writing constants in asp.net mvc. It generates constants for controller names, view names, action names, etc automatically.

Comment: i'm not sure why you are saying it is incorrect while it is working fine- i just wanted to know if there is  a better approach to this. What im simply doing is do this to get the action name,             ControllerReflector.ActionName(Index);
where index is yet another  action method. I think strings and constants are the same - they do not give much control to find out errors during the compile time - the reason why i'm trying to do it this way.

Comment: Take a look at [ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) class. Default action invoker uses this attribute. f.e. if your action method is named view, but you got [ActionName("Show")], routing will use the name "Show" as action name. Your method will return "View". "Show" != "View", so you'll get problems

Comment: i did not mention anything about ActionNameAttribute. The implementation is purly based on "typed" stuff.

Comment: If you don't use ActionNameAttribute now, it doesnt mean you won't use it in the future. There're scenarios when you just cannot make it without ActionNameAttribute, so take it into consideration

Comment: Well, then again we are falling back to the same problem with strings and constants. I do not see a scenario where we cannot manage without ActionNameAttribute, can you please give an example. Thanks anyway for helping to figure this out :)

Comment: MVCContrib takes into consideration ActionName attribute. F.e. Problems occur when you have two edit actions, one for http post, one for http get. Imagine that you would update model with Controller's UpdateModel method and don't put action parameter in post edit method. In this case, get edit and post edit have same method names and signatures. But that's impossible to have two methods with same name and signature that differ only with Http method attributes.So you rename post edit with something else. If you want to keep Edit as post action name, you have to use ActionName attribute.

Comment: Hopefully i explained well enough. post edit means [HttpPost] public ActionResult Edit() and get edit means [HttpGet] public ActionResult Edit()

Comment: @archil or create a MapRoute to handle it without ActionName attribute